# SQL UPDATE Statement - Invalid Column Name using WHERE

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to do a simple Update of a Password field but keep getting an error relating to the WHERE statement and the guidPasscode being "Invalid column name 'guidPasscode'.

I know it's probably simple but after two days I'm stumped, I just can't see the issue.
Although I have removed my debugs from this code, all data content is correct.

In the Table : 
UID is a uniqueidentifier 
DeviceType is a varchar
uPassword is a varchar

UIDPasscode is a GUID that is passed around that app.

Thanks

```
 Public Function updatePasscode(ByVal UIDpasscode As String, AppMode As String, Optional ByVal exTmplList As List(Of String) = Nothing) As Boolean

        Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(mConnectionString)
        connection.Open()
        Dim DeviceTypes As String = "P1"     

        Try

            Dim i As Integer
            Dim guidPasscode As New Guid(UIDpasscode)

            For i = 0 To 0

                Dim scanCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
                scanCommand.Connection = connection
                scanCommand.CommandType = 1 ' CommandType.Text

                Dim newPassword As String = exTmplList(i)

                Dim updateSql As String = "UPDATE tblUserScans SET DeviceType = DeviceTypes, uPassword = newPassword WHERE UID = guidPasscode"

                scanCommand.CommandText = updateSql

                scanCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

                scanCommand.Dispose()
                scanCommand = Nothing
            Next
```

UPDATE :

I just tried the following and now I am getting an error ; 

Invalid column : newPassword

```
               For i = 0 To 0

                Dim scanCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
                scanCommand.Connection = connection
                scanCommand.CommandType = 1 ' CommandType.Text

                Dim newPassword As String = exTmplList(i)

                updateSql = "Update tblUserScans SET DeviceType = 'P1', uPassword = newPassword  Where ( UID = '" & UIDpasscode & "')"

                scanCommand.Connection = mSqlconnection
                scanCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                scanCommand.Parameters.Add("@uPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                scanCommand.Parameters("@uPassword").Value = newPassword

                scanCommand.CommandText = updateSql

                scanReturn = scanCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

UPDATE :

Per the advice from @muffi I altered ;

```
updateSql = "Update tblUserScans SET DeviceType = 'P1', uPassword = newPassword  Where ( UID = '" & UIDpasscode & "')"
```

to

```
updateSql = "Update tblUserScans SET DeviceType = 'P1', uPassword = @uPassword  Where ( UID = '" & UIDpasscode & "')"
```

Working perfectly well.

Comment: Why do you add parameters and then you are not using them? ;-) Change to: `uPassword = @uPassword`

Comment: Ahaa. Bingo that did it. Cheers @muffi

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
Dim updateSql As String = "UPDATE tblUserScans SET DeviceType = DeviceTypes, uPassword = newPassword WHERE UID = '" & guidPasscode.ToString() & "';"
```

Comment: ok Mr Genius ... F0r3v3r-A-N00b ... you're right but if the OP spent 2 days already and can't get it working, then how is he going to figure out parameters? This is the QUICKEST way for him to get going ...

Comment: That’s no reason to teach how to do things wrong. We don’t answer based on what’s quickest, we answer what’s *correct*. We also should explain what is the actual problem and why the answer we give fixes it.

Comment: I wouldn't write it like this, I'd use a stored proc and pass the parameters in that way. but the OP wants to know why his/her SQL is giving this error - "Invalid column name 'guidPasscode' and that is the easiest way to demonstrate it. Why should my answer get downvoted when I clearly answer the question? Please remove the downvote.